# Using similarities.cosine (with dataset) of SurPRISE package python

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas, graphlab

### Briefing:

I'm working over Movielens 100k [Dataset](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/) for recommendation of movies. So far I've done foll.

1. Sorting of values

   `df_sorted_values = df.sort_values(['UserID', 'MovieID'])
   print type(df_sorted_values)`
2. Printing Matrix with NaN values

   `df_matrix = df.pivot_table(values='Rating', index='UserID', columns='MovieID')`
3. Performed 5 Fold CV on it

   `reader = Reader(line_format="user item rating", sep='\t', rating_scale=(1,5))
   df = Dataset.load_from_file('ml-100k/u.data', reader=reader)
   df.split(n_folds=5)`
4. I've evaluated the dataset using SVD

   `perf = evaluate(SVD(),df,measures=['RMSE','MAE'])
   print_perf(perf)`
5. **HERE I NEED THE USE SIMILARITY ALGORITHM** provided by same package (Surprise) which is written as `surprise.cosine` to Predict the missing values. This shows that it needs `(*args,**kwargs)` arguments but I'm clueless as what is actually to be passed.
6. **ONCE THE SIMILARITIES ARE GENERATED I NEED TO PRINT THE MATRIX WITH REPLACED NaN values WHICH ARE NOW PREDICTED**, later will be used for recommendation

*P.S. I'm open to different solutions from CRAB, RECSYS, PANDAS and GRAPHLAB provided they can be worked out on steps 1 to 4 as well*

My past references have been:

1. [This](http://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/similarities.html) Manual, but doesn't show on how the arguments have passed
   nor the example
2. [This](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-surprise) Which doesn't have much difference than
       first

Answer (score 0):

While computing the cosine similarity between 2 vectors is very easy (how about `1-np.dot(a,b)/(np.linalg.norm(a)*np.linalg.norm(b))`

I would recommend you to Work with `Scipy` if you don't want to implement it yourself:

`from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine`

Comment: I don't see how is it helpful for huge dataset like movie lens 100k, yet I have now found the other way round in same package. Greatful for your reply here.

Comment: if you can shed some light on how can I export dataset in Surprise package after applying algorithm, that'd be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Those similarity functions are used like these docs: [Using prediction algorithms](http://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/prediction_algorithms.html#similarity-measures-configuration) , [FAQ](http://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FAQ.html#how-to-get-the-k-nearest-neighbors-of-a-user-or-item), [The algorithm base class  - compute_similarities](http://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/algobase.html#surprise.prediction_algorithms.algo_base.AlgoBase.compute_similarities) for KNN-based algos. They are not supposed to be used like what you want to.

You may want to use the predict function if you choose to use SVD algorithm [The algorithm base class - predict](http://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/algobase.html#surprise.prediction_algorithms.algo_base.AlgoBase.predict) like:

```
# Build an algorithm, and train it.
algo = SVD()
algo.train(trainset)
uid = str(196)  # raw user id  
iid = str(302)  # raw item id  
# get a prediction for specific users and items.
pred = algo.predict(uid, iid)
```